# The Plane Made Up by the Surface Normal of the Boundary and the Propagation Direction of the EM Radiation

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

My textbook says the following:

> Reflected light consists of two contributions: the first is light that is polarised parallel ($R \pi$) and the second is light that is polarised perpendicular ($R \sigma$) to the plane of incidence. The latter is defined as the plane made up by the surface normal of the boundary and the propagation direction of the EM radiation.
>
> [image]

I'm seeking clarification with regards to this part:

> The latter is defined as the plane made up by the surface normal of the boundary and the propagation direction of the EM radiation.

Here is another diagram I found [here](https://www.edmundoptics.com/contentassets/bd02b4a1c6a1433c97387c11d52ac0c7/fig-4-itp.gif):

[image]

My understanding is that the "surface normal of the boundary" is referring to the unit vectors that are normal to the surface of incidence, directionally labelled "normal" in the diagram directly above. But I don't understand what it means by "the propagation direction of the EM radiation"? And so, what is meant by "the plane made up by the surface normal of the boundary and the propagation direction of the EM radiation"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of propagation is the direction the waves are moving in. This is the direction of the wave vector $\bf k$, and it is the direction of the ray that we draw when drawing a ray diagram. On your second diagram you have three such rays: the incoming one arriving from top left and going to the boundary, and two outgoing ones. The plane of incidence is the unique plane that contains the incoming wavevector and a vector normal to the boundary.

To find this plane, you can start with any plane going through the reflection point and containing the normal vector. Rotate such a plane around, with the normal vector as the axis around which it is rotating, until it 'hits' the incoming ray. Then it will be oriented so as to contain both the incoming ray and the normal to the surface. That's the plane you want.

Answer (score 1):

The plane of incidence is the plane of the paper on which you have down the reflectio-refraction figure (the plane made by the **normal to boundary surface** and the **direction of propagation**, as you say). 
[image]